# Convert array to string without brackets, commas, or spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to convert an array list of individual letters (e.g. {"a", "b", "c"}) into a string that is that is made from all those letters combined — in order — to make a word. So with the example above, the array would be {"a", "b", "c"} and the word would be "abc". I'm currently using the code below:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
String str = "a"; //this is just to define it before hand with a random value
*after a lot more code*
str = Arrays.toString(arr.toArray()).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

This works — I get my result without brackets or commas, but since I replaced the commas and brackets with spaces, I get "a b c" instead of "abc". Is there a way to change this so I can replace the commas with purely nothing instead of spaces? I guess a better way to phrase this would be to completely *remove* the commas and brackets.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Adding the lines where you initialize stringOne and stringTwo would help.

Comment: So do you start of with "an array of individual letters" or do you start with a single `String stringOne`? The text says one thing, the code says another.

Comment: Sorry @JLewkovich I just clarified it. I meant to say array list, not string. You can see the edits above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] sa = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
System.out.println(String.join("", sa));
```

The Stream API is defined in JDK1.8

Comment: What has this got to do with Stream API? Do you mean to say `String.join` is available since 1.8

Comment: Isn't the .join() function only available in javascript?

Comment: @AndrewChu String.join() is introduced in JDK1.8

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Stream` and [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) like

```
String[] arr = { "a", "b", "c" };
System.out.println(Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

which outputs (as requested)

```
abc
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I implement it, it gives me an error saying that  "Collectors.joining()" is not defined. So I added:

`import java.util.stream;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

at the start of my code, and then it gives me an error saying that "class stream" cannot be found. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? The Streams API requires Java 8.

Comment: @matt I'm not sure. How does one check? I'm using BlueJ to write and compile my code, however.

Comment: @Andrew Chu I'm not sure I haven't used BlueJ before, however, I think it's just your imports that are wrong. Try these (note I am importing the `Stream` class from the `java.util.stream` package. `import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;`

Comment: @matt Thanks for the help. The imports work now, but I get an error with the .collect() function, saying there's "no suitable method found for collect..."

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `java -version` and post back what version of Java that returns?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're looking to strip down anything from the input string that is not an alphabetic character, you can use this :

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(input.charAt(i))) {
            sb.append(input.charAt(i));
        }
    } 

    return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
System.out.println(stringOne);
```

What is really happening is `System.out.println` implicitly calls the `toString()` method of the array to obtain its string representation:

```
System.out.println(stringOne.toString());
```

The implementation of `Array.toString()` returns the array elements (or rather, the `toString()` representation of the array elements), comma separated.

If you would like a different representation you have two options. You can create a new array class that extends the base array class, and overrides the `toString()` method to return the desired string representation. This is .. probably not what you want to do, but it is an option.

Alternatively, you can process the array yourself and construct the desired string representation. @Elliott Frisch shows a nice way to do this using the Streams API available in Java 8.

There are many ways other ways you could achieve the same result. Here's a quick and dirty `for` loop implementation:

```
StringBuilder arrayAsString = new StringBuilder();
String delimiter = "";
for(String element : arr) {
    arrayAsString.append(delimiter).append(element);
    delimiter = ","; // I hate this idiom but it's handy for joining strings when you don't have a better .join() method available.
}

System.out.println(arrayAsString.toString()); // calling toString() explicitly for clarity, but it's not necessary
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `replaceAll()` worked for me.

```
str = Arrays.toString(arr.toArray()).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "").replaceAll(" ", "")
```

Comment: Take care of String.replaceAll()'s performance, it expects a regular expression. I don't think it's necessary in your case.